# copy the link of the current played video/stream in iOS

Tags: ios, safari, video, streaming

Is it possible to copy the link of the current played video/stream in iOS in the Safari or another 3rd party Browser? Have a look at the screenshot below in the bottom left corner.

In OS X I'm able to do it with a right click on the video/stream and then **Copy Video Address**.

[image]

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: It looks like this URL is displayed for convenience only. Is the URL not available for capture from the browser which initiated the video/stream?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I can't figure it out. In OS X it's possible with a right click and then **Copy Video Address**, but in iOS it looks like there isn't such a function. I tried to tap and hold and some other gestures. Nothing worked out for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, there is no such feature in Apples APIs at the moment. I solved it writing a short script which searches the HTML code for video URLs.

**UPDATE**:
But there's the possibility to view the url. Look at Josh Newman's answer. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/268156/153006

Comment: Would you care to share?  I'm looking to do the same thing.  Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no script which works universally. Mine is just for one website.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to copy the URL, however if you want to view the entire thing to transcribe it, start playing your video and then lock your iOS device.  The full URL should scroll by on your lock screen.

Comment: Yeah that's correct. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Only known way to me — you can find it and copy it from the website html source.

The source AFAIK cannot be shown in safari, so you can Google “view page source online” and paste your website url to the web app. Search for <video tag in the source.

I found my mp4 video url that way.